# How to search and retrieve array of results from KnockoutObservableArray<string>

Tags: javascript, jquery, knockout.js

I have below KnockoutObservableArray. I want to search and retrieve the only first 5 results from this array.

```
var people: KnockoutObservableArray<string>;
    this.people.push("abc");
    this.people.push("aaa");
    this.people.push("xyz");
    ...
```

I tried multiple options using people.filter method but could not find exactly what i required.

Can someone please help me here.

Comment: Did you try `slice`? See the [docs](https://knockoutjs.com/documentation/observableArrays.html)

Comment: First of all i could not able to search the results. Can you tell me How can i search the KnockoutObservableArray?

Comment: I see, you want to find the first 5 elements that match some criteria. Could you perhaps show a more complete sample of your code?

Comment: I want to search it first. I am not able to search the KnockoutObservableArray.

Answer (score 0):

Not totally sure what you mean by searching the array. If you want to apply some sort of test to the array items and only retrieve the items that pass then [ko.utils.arrayFilter](http://www.knockmeout.net/2011/04/utility-functions-in-knockoutjs.html)  is the way to go.

An example that filters an array and only returns values that match the value held in another observable:

```
self.KeyWorkerFilter = ko.observable('');

self.KeyWorkersFiltered = ko.computed(function () {
    // if the filter is blank then just return the whole collection
    if (!self.KeyWorkerFilter || self.KeyWorkerFilter() === '') {
        return self.TpwKeyWorkers();
    }
    var filteredKeyWorkers = ko.utils.arrayFilter(self.TpwKeyWorkers(), function (item) {
        var name = item.name.toLowerCase();
        return name.includes(self.KeyWorkerFilter().toLowerCase());
    });
    return filteredKeyWorkers;
});
```

so in your case you might be doing something like

```
var.peopleFilter = ko.computed(function() {
    return ko.utils.arrayFilter(this.people, function(item) {
        // whatever your test is
        // example: only return array items that are equal to "aaa"
        item === "aaa";
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create a [`computed`](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/computedObservables.html) property like this which will [`filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) the array based on the `searchText`. Then use [`slice`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice) to get the first 5 results:

Search for "a" in the input and you'll only be able to see the results till "ae".

```js
let viewModel = function() {
  let self = this;

  self.people = ko.observableArray(["aa", "ab", "ac", "ad", "ae", "af", "ag"]);
  self.searchText = ko.observable('');

  // When "searchText" or "people" changes, this gets computed again
  self.filteredPeople = ko.computed(function() {
    if (!self.searchText() || !self.searchText().trim()) {
      return [];
    } else {
      return self.people()
        .filter(p => p.toLowerCase().indexOf(self.searchText().toLowerCase()) > -1)
        .slice(0, 5);
    }
  });
};

ko.applyBindings(new viewModel());
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.4.2/knockout-min.js"></script>
<input type="text" data-bind="value: searchText, valueUpdate: 'keyup'" placeholder="Search...">

<div data-bind="foreach:filteredPeople">
  <span data-bind="text:$data"></span><br>
</div>
```